# How to increase text height by 3 lines on the chapter opening page in a two column document, but not on other pages?

Tags: two-column, page

My document has a two column layout and 49 lines per page except the chapter opening page, where it should be 52 lines on that page only (remaining pages to have 49 lines per page).

When I tried `\enlargethispage{52}` in `\@chapter` definition it increased the text height only for the first column, but the second column still had only 49 lines. I need both columns to have 52 lines without manual intervention, on the opening page only.

```
    \documentclass[10,twocolumn]{book}
    \usepackage{color,graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    
    \makeatletter
    
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
           \@setfontsize\normalsize{11.5}{14}
           \abovedisplayskip 14\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
           \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
           \belowdisplayshortskip 14\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
           \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
           \let\@listi\@listI}
    
    \normalsize
    
          \setlength{\textwidth}{172.6688truemm}
          \setlength{\textheight}{49\baselineskip}
          \addtolength{\textheight}{-2.5pt}
          \setlength\columnsep{18\p@}
          \setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
          \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5pc}
          \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
          \setlength{\evensidemargin}{5pc}
          \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
          \setlength{\topmargin}{21pt}
          \addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}
          \setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
          \setlength{\headsep}{15.5pt}
          \setlength\topskip{11.5pt}
          
    \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\thispagestyle{empty}\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                           \if@mainmatter
                             \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                             \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                       {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                           \else
                             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                           \fi
                        \else
                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                        \fi
                        \chaptermark{#1}%
                        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                        \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                        \if@twocolumn
                        \enlargethispage{28pt}
                          \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                        \else
                          \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                          \@afterheading
                        \fi}      
          
         
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \chapter{chapter title turn into multiple lines,    and the real exchange rate remains
    constant}
    
     It has been four decades since Thirlwall published
    his seminal paper challenging the orthodox growth
    theory that argues for endowments and technology
    as the main determinants of international growth
    rate differences. In particular, Thirlwall (1979)
    departed from the neoclassical approach and developed
    a demand side model in which countries grow
    at rates that are consistent with their balance of
    payments equilibrium, unless {they can finance}
    their deficits continuously.
    
    {\bfseries Thirlwall's} {\itshape law}, \textsc{often} {\scshape referred} to as the dynamic
    Harrod trade multiplier, states that long-run
    growth of a country can be approximated by the
    ratio of the growth of exports to the income elasticity
    of demand for imports if the balance of payments
    equilibrium on the current account is
    a requirement, and the real exchange rate remains
    constant. However, a country that continuously
    runs trade deficits must reverse its balance of payments
    in the long run. Otherwise, it would run out
    of foreign exchange, resulting in a financial crisis.
    The only way for such a country to reduce the
    deficits is to slowdown output growth, which is
    the balance of payments constraint. As a result,
    the country would grow at a rate below the maximum
    growth permitted by its supply side factors.
    
    Most of the empirical studies following Thirlwall
    (1979) on different countries confirm the validity of
    the balance of payments constraint on economic
    growth. Alonso (1999) tests the Spanish case
    between 1960 and 1994, confirming that Spain is
    constrained by the balance of payments. Hussain
    (1999) investigates the validity of Thirlwall's law in
    29 African countries and 11 East Asian Economies,
    and the balance of payments constrained growth
    model performs well. When tests for individual
    countries are conducted, the actual growth rates
    of 29 countries are not statistically different from
    the balance of payments constrained growth rates
    (see Thirlwall 2011, for an extensive review of
    studies for individual and groups of countries).
    
    Of all the countries tested empirically, the UK is
    unique regarding its balance of payments position.
    In almost all cases, the countries could be divided
    either as balance of payments constrained or not,
    while the UK cannot be classified as such.
    McCombie (1997) argues that the UK was severely
    balance of payments constrained only prior to
    1974. Although the economic growth after 1974
    was still not strong, the hypothesis that a balance
    of payments constraint existed is rejected, suggesting
    a systematic break. McCombie claimed that the
    high-volume production of North Sea Oil helped
    the UK to relieve its balance of payments constraint
    in the 1980s (more detail is discussed in McCombie
    and Thirlwall 1994, where a negative correlation
    between unemployment and current account balance
    is shown, with a break around 1974).
    
    
    As seen in Figure 1, the UK became a net oil
    exporter after the 1980s. However, the UK became
    a net oil importer once more in the new millennium.
    Consequently, the trade balance may have deteriorated
    and growth be constrained again. Our objective
    is to test whether the UK has been constrained by its
    balance of payments during 1950-2017, while allowing
    for additional structural breaks. Furthermore,
    McCombie (1997) used regressions in log first differences
    to estimate elasticities, and this may have
    resulted in a loss of long-run information in the
    data. In this paper, we estimate the income elasticity
    of imports using both Johansen Cointegration and
    Autoregressive Distributed Lags (ARDL) approaches,
    which should produce more precise results. We also
    use a new test based on a 2SLS estimation procedure,
    in addition to the two standard tests suggested in the
    literature, to test whether the UK is constrained by its
    balance of payments and to confirm the robustness of
    our results.
    
    The rest of the paper is as follows: In Section 2,
    we discuss Thirlwall's model and some of its relevant
    extensions. In Section 3, we go over different
    approaches to estimate the elasticity of demand for
    imports and test the constraint. In Section 4, we
    present our methodology followed by Section 5,
    where we discuss the empirical results. We finalize
    our paper in Section 6 with our concluding
    remarks.
    
    
    The pioneering work on the balance of payments
    constrained growth model was by Thirlwall (1979).
    In this section, we will discuss the original model
    developed by Thirlwall and some of its seminal and
    more recent extensions.
    
    
    The starting premise of the model is that no country
    can grow faster than the rate consistent with the
    balance of payments equilibrium on its current
    account, unless it can continuously finance its deficit.
    Since this is not sustainable, the balance of
    payments will need to be corrected, and as
    a result, economic growth will be constrained in
    the long run.
    
    
    To model growth under this constraint,
    Thirlwall (1979) imposes the balance of payments
    equilibrium condition on the current account,
    incorporates export and import demand functions
    and solves for the growth rate consistent with the
    long-run balance of payments equilibrium, since
    import growth is a function of domestic income
    growth.
    
    
    
    As seen in Figure 1, the UK became a net oil
    exporter after the 1980s. However, the UK became
    a net oil importer once more in the new millennium.
    Consequently, the trade balance may have deteriorated
    and growth be constrained again. Our objective
    is to test whether the UK has been constrained by its
    balance of payments during 1950-2017, while allowing
    for additional structural breaks. Furthermore,
    McCombie (1997) used regressions in log first differences
    to estimate elasticities, and this may have
    resulted in a loss of long-run information in the
    data. In this paper, we estimate the income elasticity
    of imports using both Johansen Cointegration and
    Autoregressive Distributed Lags (ARDL) approaches,
    which should produce more precise results. We also
    use a new test based on a 2SLS estimation procedure,
    in addition to the two standard tests suggested in the
    literature, to test whether the UK is constrained by its
    balance of payments and to confirm the robustness of
    our results.
    
    The rest of the paper is as follows: In Section 2,
    we discuss Thirlwall's model and some of its relevant
    extensions. In Section 3, we go over different
    approaches to estimate the elasticity of demand for
    imports and test the constraint. In Section 4, we
    present our methodology followed by Section 5,
    where we discuss the empirical results. We finalize
    our paper in Section 6 with our concluding
    remarks.
    
    
    The pioneering work on the balance of payments
    constrained growth model was by Thirlwall (1979).
    In this section, we will discuss the original model
    developed by Thirlwall and some of its seminal and
    more recent extensions.
    
    
    The starting premise of the model is that no country
    can grow faster than the rate consistent with the
    balance of payments equilibrium on its current
    account, unless it can continuously finance its deficit.
    Since this is not sustainable, the balance of
    payments will need to be corrected, and as
    a result, economic growth will be constrained in
    the long run.
    
    
    To model growth under this constraint,
    Thirlwall (1979) imposes the balance of payments
    equilibrium condition on the current account,
    incorporates export and import demand functions
    and solves for the growth rate consistent with the
    long-run balance of payments equilibrium, since
    import growth is a function of domestic income
    growth.
    
    
    
    As seen in Figure 1, the UK became a net oil
    exporter after the 1980s. However, the UK became
    a net oil importer once more in the new millennium.
    Consequently, the trade balance may have deteriorated
    and growth be constrained again. Our objective
    is to test whether the UK has been constrained by its
    balance of payments during 1950-2017, while allowing
    for additional structural breaks. Furthermore,
    McCombie (1997) used regressions in log first differences
    to estimate elasticities, and this may have
    resulted in a loss of long-run information in the
    data. In this paper, we estimate the income elasticity
    of imports using both Johansen Cointegration and
    Autoregressive Distributed Lags (ARDL) approaches,
    which should produce more precise results. We also
    use a new test based on a 2SLS estimation procedure,
    in addition to the two standard tests suggested in the
    literature, to test whether the UK is constrained by its
    balance of payments and to confirm the robustness of
    our results.
    
    The rest of the paper is as follows: In Section 2,
    we discuss Thirlwall's model and some of its relevant
    extensions. In Section 3, we go over different
    approaches to estimate the elasticity of demand for
    imports and test the constraint. In Section 4, we
    present our methodology followed by Section 5,
    where we discuss the empirical results. We finalize
    our paper in Section 6 with our concluding
    remarks.
    
    
    The pioneering work on the balance of payments
    constrained growth model was by Thirlwall (1979).
    In this section, we will discuss the original model
    developed by Thirlwall and some of its seminal and
    more recent extensions.
    
    
    The starting premise of the model is that no country
    can grow faster than the rate consistent with the
    balance of payments equilibrium on its current
    account, unless it can continuously finance its deficit.
    Since this is not sustainable, the balance of
    payments will need to be corrected, and as
    a result, economic growth will be constrained in
    the long run.
    
    
    To model growth under this constraint,
    Thirlwall (1979) imposes the balance of payments
    equilibrium condition on the current account,
    incorporates export and import demand functions
    and solves for the growth rate consistent with the
    long-run balance of payments equilibrium, since
    import growth is a function of domestic income
    growth.
    
    
    
    As seen in Figure 1, the UK became a net oil
    exporter after the 1980s. However, the UK became
    a net oil importer once more in the new millennium.
    Consequently, the trade balance may have deteriorated
    and growth be constrained again. Our objective
    is to test whether the UK has been constrained by its
    balance of payments during 1950-2017, while allowing
    for additional structural breaks. Furthermore,
    McCombie (1997) used regressions in log first differences
    to estimate elasticities, and this may have
    resulted in a loss of long-run information in the
    data. In this paper, we estimate the income elasticity
    of imports using both Johansen Cointegration and
    Autoregressive Distributed Lags (ARDL) approaches,
    which should produce more precise results. We also
    use a new test based on a 2SLS estimation procedure,
    in addition to the two standard tests suggested in the
    literature, to test whether the UK is constrained by its
    balance of payments and to confirm the robustness of
    our results.
    
    The rest of the paper is as follows: In Section 2,
    we discuss Thirlwall's model and some of its relevant
    extensions. In Section 3, we go over different
    approaches to estimate the elasticity of demand for
    imports and test the constraint. In Section 4, we
    present our methodology followed by Section 5,
    where we discuss the empirical results. We finalize
    our paper in Section 6 with our concluding
    remarks.
    
    
    The pioneering work on the balance of payments
    constrained growth model was by Thirlwall (1979).
    In this section, we will discuss the original model
    developed by Thirlwall and some of its seminal and
    more recent extensions.
    
    
    The starting premise of the model is that no country
    can grow faster than the rate consistent with the
    balance of payments equilibrium on its current
    account, unless it can continuously finance its deficit.
    Since this is not sustainable, the balance of
    payments will need to be corrected, and as
    a result, economic growth will be constrained in
    the long run.
    
    
    To model growth under this constraint,
    Thirlwall (1979) imposes the balance of payments
    equilibrium condition on the current account,
    incorporates export and import demand functions
    and solves for the growth rate consistent with the
    long-run balance of payments equilibrium, since
    import growth is a function of domestic income
    growth.
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, typesetting doesn't use lines to define the page size (text area).  Second, at the start of a new chapter (in book) there is a 50pt gap at the start of the page.  Why not just reduce the gap by 3\baselineskip?  See \@makechapterhead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, as per the styles need to fix the layout three line longer to occupy the affiliation details of author at bottom of the page as footnote

Comment: You can use \afterpage (afterpage package) to add \enlargethiscpage to the second column.  I noticed that IEEEtran.cls uses `\enlargethispage{-1.3\baselineskip}` on the first page.  You should be getting a warning about using 42 (pt added).